# Can't start Azure free trial because of MS account both doesn't exist and already exists

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

My team already has a working Azure DevOps account. I would like to start an Azure subscription / Active Directory to begin linking our DevOps to App Services and other Azure products.

However, any time I click on a link to get started with Azure, I am met with a perplexing paradox trying to log in.

First I'm told that I can't log in because my MS account isn't found:
[image: MS account not found]

But if I try to "Create one!" or "get a new Microsoft account", I'm told it already exists:
[image]

I've taken out the email address being used, but I've confirmed they are the same between the two screens (I'm not even typing anything; all I'm doing is clicking "Next" on each screen).

I know that this MS account is valid. It's the same one I use to sign in with Azure DevOps and many other MS services. I'm not sure why I can't log in to the Azure set up platform. And there doesn't seem to be any kind of support options with Azure before you become a subscriber, so I thought I'd try my luck posting the issue here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can directly file a free Azure subscription/billing ticket, via https://aka.ms/AzurePortalHelp for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your Azure DevOps organization to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). Kindly checkout this document - [About accessing your organization via Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/access-with-azure-ad?view=azure-devops)

Just to clarify, I hope you are an administrator on the subscription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops

When your sign-in address is shared by your personal Microsoft account and by your work account or school account, but your selected identity doesn't have access, you can't sign in. Although both identities use the same sign-in address, they're separate: they have different profiles, security settings, and permissions.

- Sign out completely from Azure DevOps by completing the following steps.
- Closing your browser might not sign you out completely.
- Sign in again and select your other identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops

To connect your organization to Azure AD.

- Sign in to your organization, https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}).
- Select gear icon > Organization settings.
- Select Azure Active Directory, and then select Connect directory.

Comment: If the issue persists, you can directly file a free Azure subscription/billing ticket, via aka.ms/AzurePortalHelp for assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ajay. I wasn't able to create a subscription/billing ticket, because I wasn't able to log into the portal at all using my MS account. Ultimately what I had to do was log in as a coworker to create the support ticket, and then they were able to fix whatever was wrong with my own account.

Comment: Great! Glad to know the issue is resolved. Thanks for the update.